# How to create a dictionary with repeating key values in list and list of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```py
Key_list = [1,1,1,2,2,3]

Value_list = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
```

To get something like:

```py
D = {1:['A','B','C'],2:['D','E'],3:['F']}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could loop over the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)ped keys and values, setting or updating the dict values as required:

```py
d = dict()
for k, v in zip(Key_list, Value_list):
    d[k] = d.get(k, []) + [v]
```

Output:

```
{
 1: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 2: ['D', 'E'],
 3: ['F']
}
```

Comment: Life saver worked to perfection thank you!